# scikit-learn. Передать reader в fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

У меня есть некоторая выборка данных. Она очень большая. Можно ли как-нибудь в `SVC.fit(X, y)` передавать `reader_x, reader_y` вместо `X, y`, который читает данные из БД или файла? Речь идёт о библиотке **scikit-learn**.

Comment: Почему нет? Есть только ограничения языка python, которые тут не срабатывают... Не совсем понятна суть Вашего вопроса... Как говориться: "Какие ограничения Вас интересуют?"

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `numpy.memmap`. Это позволит не читать весь файл в память и при этом будет доступ как к обычному массиву `numpy`.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич что непонятно? Мне нужно передать в fit ридеры, вместо непосредственно np.array или dataframe. Это нужно для того, чтобы организовать потоковое чтение

Comment: @Avernial покурю, спасибо

Comment: @hedgehogues, почитайте об [out of core classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html)

Comment: @MaxU, да, поглядел. А почему используется именно SGD? Почему обычный GD не реализован таким же образом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился несколько иным образом. Есть замечательный метод [SDG](http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/tricks-2012.pdf). Дока лежит [тут](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.partial_fit). Благодаря ему возможно так называемое обучение батчами, пачками. Т.е. взяли часть данных, обучились. Взяли ещё часть данных ещё дообучились и т.д. сколько угодно раз. Всё это возможно благодаря partial_fit(). Не забываем, что здесь нужно ещё указать все возможные значения Y в classes. Для сравнения:

```
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Батчи:

```
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
for count in range(0, max_count):
   X, Y = get_next_data()
   clf.partial_fit(X, Y)
```